# how to publish something on facebook from the DetailView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook, ios-4.2

i am working with publishing story on facebook in my app. its my first time working with iphone app and facebook together. i read documentation and now i can get permissions to publish. but there is a problem. i have this code in AppDelegate.m:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"app_id"];

NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"publish_stream", nil] retain];

[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    return YES;
  }

   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
  }
```

now i have a button in DetailView which should post story on user's wall. i wrote this code there:

```
    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [sTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""], @"name",
                            [sSummary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""], @"description",
                            [sLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""], @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"XXX", @"api_key",
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

and it gives error facebook undeclared at the last line. how can i remove that error. should i init that facebook in DetailViewController too or can i use already declared facebook which is in AppDelegate.m. if yes how? thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a pointer to app delegate's facebook variable

```
MyProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
facebook = appDelegate.facebook;
```

I Hope this helped you.